# Rails 7 - ActiveModel date validation | Is there a replacement for validates_timeliness gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel, model-validation, ruby-on-rails-7

- While trying to upgrade my application to Rails 7, I came across the following deprecation warning : `ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1. Use` ActiveRecord.default_timezone `instead.`
- On further inspection, i found that this is being thrown by the `validates_timeliness` gem which has not been updated yet.
- A PR addressing this issue has been made by [Mitsuru](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/pull/213), but the owner of the gem hasn't merged it yet. I'm guessing that the gem isn't being actively worked on now.
- My question is this, in Rails 7, can I validate Date and Time (formats and >,< operations) without using an external gem?
- If not, is there a replacement for validates_timeliness gem that is actively being worked on?
- In my app, the way that i'm using the validates_timeliness gem is as follows :

  ```
    validates :graduation_date, 
              timeliness: { type: :date }, 
              unless: lambda{ |e| e.graduation_date_not_required.present? }


    validates :start_date, timeliness: { type: :date }
    validates :end_date, timeliness: { type: :date }, unless: :is_current?
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the Rails' new [Comparision Validator](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison)

Try using like this:

```rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  validates :start_date, presence: true
  validates :end_date, presence: true
  
  validates_comparison_of :end_date, greater_than: :start_date, other_than: Date.today
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rabin. However, the above does not check the type for the :start_date, it only checks whether its nil or not. How can I check whether its a Date instance?

Comment: Hi @KabirPathak if your column type is datetime or date, Rails does not accept other instances than date.